# Drawing a complete binary tree from postorder

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, computer-science, binary

I've been trying to solve this problem as a practice:

The complete binary tree has V = {a, b, c, e, f, g, h, i, j, k}. The postorder listing of V yields {d, e, b, h, i, f, j, k, g, c, a}. From this information draw T if:

a) the height of T is 3

b) the height of the left subtree of T is 3

Now for a, I drew this, which I think is correct.

[image]

For b, I'm confused. I'm not sure how this is possible. I checked the solution and saw this:

[image]

How is this correct? Shouldn't complete binary trees be full at height-1? I'm not even sure if it's possible to draw this tree. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. Typically you use the values to separate left from right children, but nothing like that seems to be going on here. So, I understand your choice of making the tree as 'complete' as possible for doing problem a (i.e. filling up all levels and then for the incomplete level putting the nodes as far left as possible) ... though it is not clear to me that you *have* to do this, and as the posted andswer for b shows, it seems like just about any shape tree will do ... but if that is the case, then a lot of other trees will give you the same postorder reading!

Comment: And yes, with a left subtree of height 3, the tree as a whole cannot be made complete, because with this many nodes a complete tree has to be of height 3. So yes, I share your confusion

Comment: @Bram28: It doesn't seem to say anywhere the tree must be a binary _search_ tree.

Answer (score 1):

The solution to your confusion is simple: both solutions are correct. Indeed,
neither pre-, in- or post-order describes the underlying tree uniquely. Even if you have pre-order and post-order, it does not suffice to describe the tree. However, having pre- and in-order (or post- and in-order) suffices to describe the tree. See [Tree traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) for more details.

**EDIT**. As Henning Makholm pointed out, the OP's answer is correct if you restrict to complete binary tree in Knuth's sense. Just be aware that this definition is not fully accepted. For instance, Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest and Stein use a more restricted definition (all leaves have the same depth), which would not make sense in the context of this question. But I have also seen a "middle term" definition: all leaves have depth $n$ or $n-1$ for some $n$. With this definition, several solutions are again possible.

Comment: However, if the OP quoted the exercise correctly, it was asking for a _complete_ binary tree, which the one in the purported solution isn't.

Comment: @henning-makholm Thanks. I will edit my answer.